# Do Not Show Thumbnails when I open a new tab in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, browser

This is what my Google Chrome looks like when I open up a new tab:

[image]

Now, is it possible for me to hide away all the thumbnails when I fire up my "new tab" option ( ***not* when I launch my Google Chrome**)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taken from the [Google Chrome Help Forum](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=6e623e90b9ea2362&hl=en):

> The only way I know to do this is to
>   go into incognito mode.  To do this
>   hold down ctrl+shift+n and this will
>   open a new window in incognito mode.
>
> If you want to run in incognito mode
>   all the time you can append --icognito
>   to your shortcut.  So it would look
>   this:
>   "...\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
>   --incognito

Answer (score 2):

Click the *drop down arrow* & click on the **most visited** & **recently closed** options (which would have been selected before). Now you'll have a new tab just like the one you get in an incognito window

Comment: drop down arrow... where is it?

Comment: http://img121.imageshack.us/img121/2522/beforey.jpg
http://img265.imageshack.us/img265/2411/afterj.jpg 
- see the third button in the top right corner

Comment: Great tips. However, one can still view the most visited information if he knows how.

Comment: I thought your question was how to hide them when you open a new tab. If someone does know how to revert that back to default like you said then they can view that. Guess you have to delete your history if you want to have it all cleaned up

Comment: @Avis your image links in the comment are "404 Not Found"... (not sure if the answers are supported anymore in Chrome anyway)

Answer (score 0):

You can select to open your home page (which can be about:blank) when you open a new tab. Go to Tools > Options > Basic > Home Page.

[image]

Comment: It doesn't work; after setting the setting according to your screenshot, when I new a tab ( *not* when I launch Google Chrome), I still get the same screenshot.

Comment: You have to restart google chrome after making above changes.

Comment: I did, but still it doesn't work

Comment: Are you sure you are using Google Chrome? The screenshot look dangerously like chromium. Why not try to re-installing directly from google site (http://www.google.com/chrome)?

Comment: @Hemant: Have you tried your own solution? I am using Google Chrome 4.0.223.11

Answer (score 0):

Try this extension, [Chrome Web Store - New Tab Redirect!](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/icpgjfneehieebagbmdbhnlpiopdcmna)

It solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Can be easily fixed by using small extensions like

[New tab blanker](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/new-tab-blanker-for-googl/lipkjlkpkblbmidenmdhdkeigcbngimi)

[Empty new tab](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/empty-new-tab-page/dpjamkmjmigaoobjbekmfgabipmfilij)